# Groovy MultivaluedHash Map

Tags: groovy

Can someone help me to solve the problem

**Problem Description**
Create a class Asset with the following member variables.
def `name`
def `assetNumber`
def `model`
def `lastAssignedDate`
def `price`
Input Format:
The first input corresponds to string asset name.
The second input corresponds to an integer asset number.
The third input corresponds to string asset model.
The fourth input corresponds to the date last assigned the date.
The fifth input corresponds to double asset price.
Next input is a string denotes when there is one more asset detail or not. (Yes/No)

Output Format:
If the `assetNumber` is found print `Asset with _assetNumber_ found.` or `Asset with _assetNumber_ not found.`
Refer sample input and output. [All bold text corresponds to input and rest are the output.]

Asset `name:name1`
Asset `number:1`
Asset `model:mod1`
Assigned `date:01/01/2015`
Price: `100.24`
Do you want to continue? (Yes/No): Yes
Asset `name:name2`
Asset `number:2`
Asset `model:mod2`
Assigned `date:01/01/2016`
Price: `200.24`
Do you want to continue? (Yes/No): No
1
2
Enter the number to search:
The asset with 2 found.

**My Code**

```
def class Asset
{
  def name;
  def assetNumber
  def model
  def lastAssignedDate
  def price

  def constructAsset(Map classMap)
  {
    this.name=classMap['name'];
    this.assetNumber=classMap['assetNumber'];
    this.model=classMap['model'];
    this.lastAssignedDate=classMap['lastAssignedDate'];
    this.price=classMap['price']
    return classMap; 
  }
  def findNumber(Map classMap,int num) 
  {
    //println classMap
    for ( e in classMap )
    {
      if ("${e.key}" == "assetNumber")
      {    
        println ("${e.value}")  
      }  
    }
    def myKey = classMap.find{ it.value == num }?.key;
    if(myKey)
    {println("Asset with " + num + " found.")}
    else
    {println("Asset with " + num + " not found.")}

   }


}
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

def name;
def assetNumber;
def model
def lastAssignedDate
def price
def cont="Yes"
Asset a=new Asset();
def list=[:]
while(cont=="Yes")
{
  println("Asset name:");
  name=br.readLine();

  println("Asset number:");
  assetNumber=br.readLine().toInteger();

  println("Asset model:")
  model=br.readLine()  

  println("Assigned date:")
  lastAssignedDate=br.readLine();
  lastAssignedDate=Date.parse("dd/mm/yyyy", lastAssignedDate).format("dd-mm-yyyy")

  println("Price:")
  price=br.readLine().toDouble()
  list << a.constructAsset(name:"$name",assetNumber:"$assetNumber",model:"$model",lastAssignedDate:"$lastAssignedDate",price:"$price");

  println("Do you want to continue?(Yes/No)");
  cont=br.readLine();


}
println("Enter the number to search:")
def num=br.readLine().toInteger();
a.findNumber(list,num)
```

**Expected Output**
Asset name:name1
Asset number:1
Asset model:mod1
Assigned date:01/01/2015
Price:100.24
Do you want to continue? (Yes/No): Yes
Asset name:name2
Asset number:2
Asset model:mod2
Assigned date:01/01/2016
Price:200.24
Do you want to continue? (Yes/No): No
1
2
Enter the number to search:
The asset with 2 found.

**Actual Output**
Asset name:name1
Asset number:1
Asset model:mod1
Assigned date:01/01/2015
Price:100.24
Do you want to continue? (Yes/No): Yes
Asset name:name2
Asset number:2
Asset model:mod2
Assigned date:01/01/2016
Price:200.24
Do you want to continue? (Yes/No): No
1
2
Enter the number to search:
The asset with 2 found.

**Issue**
When adding key values, map always holds the recently entered value.
So when I am printing asset number value, it's printing the recent value. But not printing the first value entered. In this example expecting Asset Numbers 1 and 2. But printing only 2. (Next to Do you want to continue? (Yes/No))

Comment: You only create a single Asset object, as the Asset a=new Asset(); is outside the while loop. Your list variable is a Map, so adding using the leftshift operator << just updates the map based on existing object.
You should probably move a=new Asset() into the loop, and when adding the object to the list (assuming assetNumber is unique):  list[ assetNumber] = a.constructAsset(name:"$name",assetNumber:"$assetNumber",model:"$model",lastAssignedDate:"$lastAssignedDate",price:"$price")

Comment: Thank you. It works after adding a=new Asset() into the loop.